# JDK 1.6 compatible with JDK 1.5?

Tags: compatibility, java, backwards-compatibility

Im having a compatible issue, my project is develop in JDK 1.6, but when i need to post it to a host domain, there is a issue where the host domain used JDK 1.5, how do i make my project compatible with JDK 1.5? thanks in advance

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You basically need to set the `-target` attribute. Also see `javac /?`.

```
javac -target 1.5 [...]
```

Also see [this example](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/technotes/tools/windows/javac.html#crosscomp-example) in javac's documentation.

---

**Update**: as per the comments you're using Eclipse, you can just change the compiler compliance level on a per-project basis. *Rightclick project > Properties > Java Compiler > Compiler compliance level > 1.5*. [See screenshot](https://tweakers.net/ext/f/8Yu4AYKmTma1vQHuAWY58Kth/full.png).

[image]

You can download JDK 1.5 from the [Sun Archive](http://java.sun.com/products/archive/).

Comment: can i convert it straight a way in WAR file??

Comment: No, the code must be compiled with 1.5 as the output language. The class file format has been changed in JDK6.

Comment: Need `-source 1.5` as well, and putting the 1.5 `rt.jar` file in `-bootclasspath` is also very useful.

Comment: @kojh: if you're using an IDE (you should have make that more clear in your question), you need to set the project's compiler compliance level to 1.5 as answered by @mikera and then just rebuild the project.

Comment: thanks BalusC, im actually developing the my project using eclipse bundle with glassfish. Sorry for that :)

Comment: BalusC does ur first suggestion still can be used to compile my projects even if i have eclipse ??

Comment: Certainly. It's all up to you how you'd like to compile your code. Both can be used independently.

Answer (score 3):

You should be able to set the compliance level on your compiler / IDE to 1.5 so that any incompatibilities are flagged (via compiler warnings). You can then fix whatever needs to be done to make your code 1.5 compatible.

In Eclipse for example, you go to Preferences / Java / Compiler and set the compliance level to 1.5. It's probably something similar in other IDEs.