# Faceted Project Eclipse environment

Tags: eclipse, installation, facet

Even if I have checked this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2239959/setting-the-compiler-versions) and try the solution on it, the problem is still there.

Java compiler level does not match the version of the installed Java project facet. Project-name Unknown    Faceted Project Problem (Java Version Mismatch)

Comment: Could you give more details? What exactly are you trying to do and when are you getting the error?

Comment: The problem was just installing an existing maven project, and conflicting versions.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Eclipse gives up a solution.
Just click right mouse over the problem, in the Problems view, Choose "Quick Fix", and run with another version which I was running before.

Comment: And restart the eclipse for settings to reflect.

Answer (score 6):

Go to project properties, check the Project Facets section, set the correct JRE

Answer (score 3):

on properties of the project and go to project facets, at this point you must change the versión of java, just right click on java and change to prior version.
or go to java build path an change the server libraries, or go to server and change the server. if it not solvethe problem

Answer (score 1):

First of all right click your project and then go to java compiler,Check the Compiler compliance level,Fix your correct java edition.