# Java compiler level does not match the version of the installed Java project facet

Tags: eclipse, maven, m2eclipse

I have created a New Dynamic Project under Eclipse Helios Version, where my JRE Version is set to 1.6.
I have added Maven capabilities to the Web Application by clicking on *Configure* → *Convert to Maven Project*.

After adding this, a build error appeared in the Eclipse Problems view:

```
Java compiler level does not match the version of the installed Java project facet.
Unknown Faceted Project Problem (Java Version Mismatch)
```

Please tell me how to resolve this error (I want to have my JRE version as 1.6 only).

Comment: Bigleftie's answer served me well for a non Maven project.

Comment: eclipse users can read this
https://www.journaldev.com/3334/eclipse-java-compiler-level-does-not-match-the-version-of-the-installed-java-project-facet

Comment: Possible duplicate of ["Faceted Project Problem (Java Version Mismatch)" error message](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2239959/faceted-project-problem-java-version-mismatch-error-message)

Answer (score 176, accepted):

Assuming that you are using the m2e plugin in Eclipse, you'll need to specify the `source` and `target` versions as 1.6 for `maven-compiler-plugin`. m2e uses these values to determine the project's Java compiler level. A snippet of the POM is shown below:

```
<build>
  <plugins>
    <plugin>
      <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
        <configuration>
          <source>1.6</source>
          <target>1.6</target>
        </configuration>
    </plugin>
  </plugins>
</build>
```

Alternatively, you can specify the `maven.compiler.source` and `maven.compiler.target` properties with values of 1.6, that happen to be the equivalent:

```
<properties>
    <maven.compiler.target>1.6</maven.compiler.target>
    <maven.compiler.source>1.6</maven.compiler.source>
</properties>
```

Comment: Can you do it:
- Right-click on your project
- Click Properties
- Click the "Project Facets" option on the left menu
- Under Facets section "Java" on the right, change it to "1.6", "1.7" or your version...
- Click Ok

Comment: @ThiagoPereira You lose those changes when you reimport in a different workspace. Learn how m2e works.

Comment: eclipse users can read https://www.journaldev.com/3334/eclipse-java-compiler-level-does-not-match-the-version-of-the-installed-java-project-facet

Answer (score 453):

If your project is not a Maven project, right-click on your project and choose Properties to open the Project Properties dialog.

There is a Project Facets item on the left, select it, look for the Java facet on the list, choose which version you want to use for the project and apply.

[image: Project Factes - Java version]

Comment: The Project Facet->Java should match whatever you have in the pom.xml for the maven-compiler-plugin artifact source and target.

Comment: The root cause of this problem should be the answer provided by @VineetReynolds

Comment: I have this problem, and it sounds like it's a maven issue, but I don't use maven, I don't have a POM file, and I'm not even sure I have the maven plugin.  Yet I get this same error; my eclipse is set up to use java 1.7 but the facet page of my project will only let me choose 1.6.  What am I doing wrong?

Comment: After doing this, the original Java library was removed from the Build Path and a new library (associated with the *Project Facet Java* setting) was added to the **end** of the build path. If this happens, restore the original Java library in the correct position in the Build Path (*Note:* To do this, you should've made a backup of the `.classpath` file before attempting the answer.) Then do a clean build (*Project > Clean*). If `X` continues to appear in the *Project Explorer* without any actual errors in *Markers*, close and re-open the project to make it go away.

Comment: Four things must match 1) Project->Java Build Path->Libraries->JRE version 2) Project->Java Compiler-> Compiler Compliance Level 3) Project->Project Facets->Java->Version 4) (if using Maven) pom.xml - maven-compiler-plugin artifact source and target

Comment: I second @TK Gospodinov answer. my pom was upto date with Java version but project facet was the culprit.

Comment: Awesome, I've spent too much time trying to fix this problem, now I've finally done it. It's worth mentioning that this worked for me even though mine is a maven project.

Comment: Up-voted. This helped me. Clear, right to the point. An Image tells 1000 words they say.

Comment: I dont know if @bigleftie comment is correct, but it resolved my issues.

Comment: don't see java 1.11 there

Answer (score 18):

TK Gospodinov answer is correct even for maven projects. Beware: I do use Maven. The pom was correct and still got this issue. I went to "Project Facets" and actually removed the Java selection which was pointing to 1.6 but my project is using 1.7. On the right in the "Runtimes" tab I had to check the jdk1.7 option. Nothing appeared on the left even after I hit "Apply". The issue went away though which is why I still think this answer is important of the specific "Project Facets" related issue. After you hit OK if you come back to "Project Facets" you will notice Java shows up as version 1.7 so you can now select it to make sure the project is "marked" as a Java project. I also needed to right click on the project and select Maven|Update Project.

Answer (score 13):

I found @bigleftie's comment above very helpful:
"Four things must match

1. Project->Java Build Path->Libraries->JRE version
2. Project->Java Compiler-> Compiler Compliance Level
3. Project->Project Facets->Java->Version
4. (if using Maven) pom.xml - maven-compiler-plugin artefact source and target".

In my case, in the project properties, Java compiler, the JDK compliance was set to use the workspace settings, which were different from the java version for the project. I clicked on 'Configure Workspace Settings', and changed the workspace Compiler compliance level to what I wanted, and the problem was resolved.

Answer (score 7):

I resolved this problem by setting the java version in Project Facet property of the project properties, Right click the project root folder -> Properties, search for Project Facets, and select compatible java version.

For reference -

[image]

Answer (score 6):

I resolved it by **Myproject**--->**java Resource**---->**libraries**-->J**RE System Libraries[java-1.6]** click on this go to its "**property**" select **"Classpath Container"** change the **Execution Environment** to java-1.8(jdk1.8.0-35) (that is **latest**)

[image: Change the jdk to latest]

Answer (score 5):

I changed the configuration inside `workspace/project/.setting/org.eclipse.wst.common.project.facet.core` to :

```
installed facet="jst.web" version="2.5"
installed facet="jst.java" version="1.7"
```

Before changing config, remove project from IDE.
This worked for me.

Comment: just removed the project from eclipse and re-imported fixed the issue.

Answer (score 4):

The Project Facet->Java should match whatever you have in the pom.xml for the maven-compiler-plugin artifact source and target.This is perfect.But if you donot have it here then you can also fix it by matching Java compiler version in Porject-Facets from the setting: Eclispe->Preferences->Java->Compiler

Answer (score 4):

You can change project facet from
Project --> Properties --> Project Facet --> Java --> {required JDK version}

Answer (score 3):

Right click the project and select properties 
Click the java compiler from the left and change to your required version
Hope this helps

Answer (score 2):

In Eclipse, right click on your project, go to Maven> Update projetc. Wait and the error will disappear. This is already configured correctly the version of Java for this project.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

If using eclipse,

Under.settings click on org.eclipse.wst.common.project.facet.core.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<faceted-project>
  <installed facet="java" version="1.7"/>
</faceted-project>
```

Change the version to the correct version.