# The method getDefault() is undefined for the type SSLContext?

Tags: java, ssl

I am getting the mentioned error in eclipse while importing my project. I already added jsse jar in java build path.
The error code is `var = SSLContext.getDefault().getSocketFactory();`

I didn't find resolution on google. Thanks in Advance

Comment: I don't see any method `setDefault` with what you posted. However, if you go through the doc you'll see that `setDefault` takes a parameter. http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/net/ssl/SSLContext.html#setDefault(javax.net.ssl.SSLContext)

Comment: @ZouZou Sorry... it was getDefault()

Comment: Are you sure that you've imported the right package ? (`javax.net.ssl.SSLContext`)

Comment: Which version of Java are you using? `getDefault()` was introduced in Java 6.

Comment: @ZouZou Yes,this is imported.

Answer (score 2):

> I already added jsse jar in java build path.

The JSSE has been part of the main JRE for a while (Java 1.4 as far as I remember). Whatever version you've added to the build path is certainly an old version that conflicts with the default version: don't add that extra library, use what's already in the JSSR (no need to add security providers explicitly in general, if you're following old instructions).

Comment: I am using java 6. Removing jsse jar from build path gives error...The import javax.net.ssl.... cannot be resolved. I am confused as by default my eclipse should use installed java 6,and if already has the jsse jar then why this error?  May be i need to adjust project specific setting in java compiler or to change something in project facets... Please guide me.  Thanks

Comment: There should be a `jsse.jar` in your "JRE System Libraries" section in your Eclipse project, but not an additional one. I'm not sure what you've done with your installation, but you could check you haven't changed the JRE structure on disk too.

Answer (score 0):

If you're using `Java 6`, the version which adds `getDefault()`, then you must be accessing a different class named `SSLContext` - try `javax.net.ssl.SSLContext.getDefault()`.

Comment: Yes, we're using java 6. var=javax.net.ssl.SSLContext.getDefault().getSocketFactory();    also not worked

Comment: Make sure your compiler level is set to java 6. [This link](http://stackoverflow.com/q/7715260/2970947) may help.