# Does maven.compiler.source & maven.compiler.target work for any IDE

Tags: java, maven

**NOTE:** This is not a duplicate of the question I have already linked too...I am asking a different question about whether the plugin is required for any IDE.

Looking at this answer here: [Java compiler level does not match the version of the installed Java project facet](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7715260/java-compiler-level-does-not-match-the-version-of-the-installed-java-project-fac), it mentions that I can add the following properties:

```
<properties>
    <maven.compiler.target>1.6</maven.compiler.target>
    <maven.compiler.source>1.6</maven.compiler.source>
</properties>
```

and the IDE will select the correct version of JDK.

Are these properties specific to the m2e plugin or Eclipse or are they properties that maven itself searches for? What I am asking is, do I need the `maven-compiler-plugin` referenced?

Comment: Not sure why there is any downvotes...I've read the linked question again and cannot find the answer to my question.