# Unable to create requested service [org.hibernate .engine.jdbc.env.spi.JdbcEnvironment]-MySQL

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, maven

I am a newbie to Hibernate. I am currently using Spring boot framework and trying to create database tables through hibernate.

I know the same question is asked before but I can't seem to figure out how to fix the error based on my environment.

hibernate.cfg.xml

```
<hibernate-configuration>
<session-factory>
    <!-- Database connection settings -->
    <property name="connection.driver_class">org.mm.mysql.Driver</property>
    <property name="connection.url">jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306</property>
    <property name="connection_userid">user</property>
    <property name="connection_pwd">pass</property>

    <!-- JDBC connection pool (use the built-in) -->
    <property name="connection_pool_size">true</property>

    <!-- SQL dialect -->
    <property name="dialect">org.hibernate.MySQLDialect</property>

    <!-- Disable the second-level cache -->
    <property name="cache.provider_class">org.hibernate.NoCacheProvider</property>

    <!-- Echo all executed SQL to stdout -->
    <property name="show_sql">1</property>

    <!-- Drop and re-create the database schema on startup -->
    <property name="hbmdl.auto">update</property>

    <!-- Names the annotated entity class -->
    <mapping class="com.test.springboot.model.AdultParticipant" />

</session-factory>
```

main class

```
     public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    SpringApplication.run(WebApplication.class, args);

    Configuration cfg = new Configuration();
    cfg.configure("hibernate.cfg.xml");
    SessionFactory factory = cfg.buildSessionFactory();

    Session session = factory.openSession();
    Transaction t = session.beginTransaction();

    AdultParticipant ap = new AdultParticipant();
    ap.setFirstName("User"); 
    ap.setLastName("UserLastName");

    session.persist(ap);

    t.commit();

    session.close();
    System.out.println("successfully saved");
```

POJO class

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "adultparticipant")
public class AdultParticipant {

@GeneratedValue
@Id
@Column (name = "id")
private int id;

@Column (name = "firstName")
private String firstName;

@Column (name = "lastName")
private String lastName;


public int getId() {
    return id;
}
public void setId(int id) {
    this.id = id;
}


public String getFirstName() {
    return firstName;
}
public void setFirstName(String firstName) {
    this.firstName = firstName;
}

public String getLastName() {
    return lastName;
}
public void setLastName(String lastName) {
    this.lastName = lastName;
  }
}
```

DAOImpl class

```
  public class AdultParticipantDAOImpl implements AdultParticipantDAO{
private SessionFactory sessionFactory;
public void setSessionFactory(SessionFactory sessionFactory) {
    this.sessionFactory = sessionFactory;
}

@Override
public void save(AdultParticipant ap) {
    Session session = this.sessionFactory.openSession();
    Transaction tx = session.beginTransaction();
    session.persist(ap);
    tx.commit();
    session.close();
}

@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
@Override
public List<AdultParticipant> list() {
    Session session = this.sessionFactory.openSession();
    List<AdultParticipant> adultParticipants = session.createQuery("from AdultParticipant").list();
    session.close();
    return adultParticipants;
 }
}
```

DAO class

```
public interface AdultParticipantDAO {

public void save(AdultParticipant p);

public List<AdultParticipant> list();

}
```

POM.xml

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
 <project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
<artifactId>hello-springboot</artifactId>
<name>hello-springboot</name>
<description>hello-springboot</description>
<packaging>war</packaging>
<parent>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
    <version>1.3.5.RELEASE</version>
</parent>

<properties>
    <java.version>1.8</java.version>
</properties>

<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-tomcat</artifactId>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.tomcat.embed</groupId>
        <artifactId>tomcat-embed-jasper</artifactId>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>mysql</groupId>
        <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
        <version>5.1.40</version>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```

ERROR in Console

```
2017-03-13 11:48:40.512  WARN 9532 --- [           main] org.hibernate.orm.connections.pooling    : HHH10001002: Using H
ibernate built-in connection pool (not for production use!)
Exception in thread "main" org.hibernate.service.spi.ServiceException: Unable to create requested service [org.hibernate
.engine.jdbc.env.spi.JdbcEnvironment]
    at org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.createService(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:271)
    at org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.initializeService(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:233)
    at org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.getService(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:210)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.JdbcServicesImpl.configure(JdbcServicesImpl.java:51)
```

Comment: Can you share full stack trace?

Comment: Thank you. I've updated it.

Answer (score 8):

Upgrade MySql driver to [mysql-connector-java - 8.0.17](https://app.box.com/s/hmppqnnfk33hi1o8x2twi1j8j0dc2p3a) and

Those who are using **[greater than MySQL 5.5](https://dev.mysql.com/downloads/connector/j/5.1.html)** version

change their driver property

from **`com.mysql.jdbc.Driver`** to **`com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver`**

because:

> Loading class com.mysql.jdbc.Driver. This is deprecated. The new
>   driver class is com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver. The driver is automatically
>   registered via the SPI and manual loading of the driver class is
>   generally unnecessary.INFO - HHH000401: using driver
>   [com.mysql.jdbc.Driver] at URL....

in **`hibernate.properties`**

```
hibernate.connection.driver_class = com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver
```

**or** if you are using **`hibernate.cfg.xml`** update

```
<property name="connection.driver_class">com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver</property>
```

Answer (score 4):

`connection.driver_class` property must be compatible with `mysql-connector` jar.

`mysql-connector` < `5.5.xx` use `com.mysql.jdbc.Driver`

`mysql-connector` > `5.5.xx` use `com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver`

Answer (score 3):

```
 <property name="connection.url">jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/test?serverTimezone=UTC</property>
```

You need  to set  `serverTimezone`.

Answer (score 2):

Use HSQLDialect not MYSQLDialect

```
spring.jpa.database-platform=org.hibernate.dialect.HSQLDialect
spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=none
spring.jpa.show-sql=true


spring.datasource.url=jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/xyz?serverTimezone=CST6CDT
spring.datasource.username=root
spring.datasource.password=root
spring.datasource.driverClassName=com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to add `mysql` JDBC jar in your dependencies.

---

1. Fix your driver class name as `com.mysql.jdbc.Driver`.
2. Fix your username and password property as

   ```
   "connection.username" for database user
   "connection.password" for database user password
   ```
3. Create mysql database. See [this](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/create-database.html).
4. For SSL warning, modify your connection.url to include use ssl false. For example, `jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/<enter-your-database>?autoReconnect=true&useSSL=false`
5. Modify your mysql dialect to `org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect`
6. Use `<property name="hbmdl.auto">create-drop</property>` instead of `<property name="hbmdl.auto">update</property>` however *do not* use this option in production. You should create schema yourself and not do it via hibernate.

Comment: I added  
<dependency>
  <groupId>mysql</groupId>
  <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
  <version>5.1.40</version>
</dependency> I still get the same error.

Comment: Can you also fix your driver class name as ` com.mysql.jdbc.Driver`

Comment: I changed the driver class. I get this error.
Mon Mar 13 13:31:53 EDT 2017 WARN: Establishing SSL connection without server's identity verification is not recommended
. According to MySQL 5.5.45+, 5.6.26+ and 5.7.6+ requirements SSL connection must be established by default if explicit 
option isn't set. For compliance with existing applications not using SSL the verifyServerCertificate property is set to
 'false'. You need either to explicitly disable SSL by setting useSSL=false, or set useSSL=true and provide truststore f
or server certificate verification.

Comment: and, Exception in thread "main" org.hibernate.service.spi.ServiceException: Unable to create requested service [org.hibernate
.engine.jdbc.env.spi.JdbcEnvironment]

Comment: See my modified answer

Comment: Thank you so much! 
When I include ?autoReconnect = true & useSSL = false, I get a compile error; Java compiler level does not match the version of the installed Java project facet.

Comment: check http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7715260/java-compiler-level-does-not-match-the-version-of-the-installed-java-project-fac

Comment: based on the stackoverflow,
I've added the code in the pom file
<plugin>
    <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
    <configuration>
     <source>1.8</source>
     <target>1.8</target>
    </configuration>
   </plugin>
It still doesn't work..

Comment: I have modified my answer (dialect was wrong). Check if it works.

Comment: Thank you! For creating database #3, is that optional? I understood that JPA will auto generate the db tables using mapped annotations.

Comment: I might have misunderstood what you meant by creating database. I had already created database. (I included database name in URL config now) I just want to successfully create tables.. I've fixed many issues thanks to your help, but I still get the same JDBC environment error.

Comment: Can you share your hibernate.cfg and console logs again ? I have added another point in my answer.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue when I deployed my war file to tomcat in my demo environment.
My application was not getting started because, in my /tomcat/webapp/ROOT folder, I found my war file Myapp.war there. 
i.e. In my ROOT folder, it has
WEB-INF, META-INF, and Myapp.war, which caused the startup issue.
I deleted the war file and it worked.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem: the mistake I was making was having a double line defined between the properties. So you have to be very careful that the main connection properties are correct.

Secondly, make sure that the specified dialect is correct for the DB version you are using. To see the various dialects you need to go to the hibernate-core-5.3.1.Final.jar file and from there look for the org.hybernate.dialect package which lists the various dialects available.

```
<hibernate-configuration>
    <session-factory>
        <!-- Database connection settings -->
        <property name="connection.driver_class">com.mysql.jdbc.Driver</property>
        <!-- property name="connection.driver_class">com.mysql.jdbc.Driver</property  com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver -->
        <property name="connection.url">jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/test</property>
        <property name="connection.username">root</property>
        <property name="connection.password">mypassword</property>

        <!-- JDBC connection pool (use the built-in) -->
        <property name="connection.pool_size">1</property>

        <!-- SQL dialect -->
        <!--<property name="dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect</property>-->
        <property name="dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL5Dialect</property>

        <!-- Disable the second-level cache -->
        <property name="cache.provider_class">org.hibernate.cache.internal.NoCacheProvider</property>

        <!-- Echo all executed SQL to stdout -->
        <property name="show_sql">true</property> 
        <property name="format_sql">true</property>

        <property name="current_session_context_class">thread</property>

        <!-- Drop and re-create the database schema on startup -->
        <property name="hbm2ddl.auto">update</property>  

        <!-- Names the annotated entity class -->
        <mapping class="org.test.connection.UserDetails" />

    </session-factory>

</hibernate-configuration>
```