# Spring - Apache and XML error

Tags: eclipse, spring, tomcat, eclipse-juno

I was following [this tutorial](http://www.roseindia.net/spring/spring-mvc-login-example.shtml) for Spring Login example. I downloaded their sample code and import in my Eclipse. It throws 2 error.

**Error 1**
Target runtime Apache Tomcat v6.0 (2) is not defined. Unknown   Faceted Project Problem

**Error 2**
Referenced file contains errors (http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee/web-app_2_5.xsd).

I already download the latest updates in eclipse and reinstall the tomcat.
Using Tomcat6,Spring-3.2.0.RC1.

[image]

Please advice. Thanks

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2239959/faceted-project-prblem-java-version-mismatch-error-message ? what is the target runtime? is it a jave ee eclipse? Why are you using roseindia and Spring 2.5 when there's official documentation with sample projects that is developed by SpringSource http://static.springsource.org/spring-security/site/docs/3.1.x/reference/sample-apps.html

Comment: @BorisTreukhov managed to solved the tomcat issue by changing the target runtime.. thanks for it.. yes eclipse ee.. i googled and found the link...there is no special reason why i use roseindia...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We need to right click on the project, properties and Targeted Runtimes. Uncheck the old server entry and enable the new entry. This should solve this error.

http://javashine.wordpress.com/2010/09/07/target-runtime-apache-tomcat-v6-0-is-not-defined/

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

Right click on the project->select properties option.

Search for targetedruntimes in the search bar

uncheck the tomcat old version

select latest version and the version you wnat to use.