# How can i solve this error when i import the project at my home then this error occured

Tags: jakarta-ee

Description Resource    Path    Location    Type
Target runtime Apache Tomcat v6.0 is not defined.   Online_suppprt_System_y     Unknown Faceted Project Problem

Description Resource    Path    Location    Type
Unbound classpath container: 'JRE System Library [jdk1.6.0]' in project 'Online_suppprt_System_y'   Online_suppprt_System_y     Build path  Build Path Problem

Description Resource    Path    Location    Type
The import java.sql cannot be resolved  EmployeeMenu.jsp    /Online_suppprt_System_y/WebContent line 6  JSP Problem

Description Resource    Path    Location    Type
Unbound classpath container: 'JRE System Library [jdk1.6.0]' in project 'Online_suppprt_System_y'   Online_suppprt_System_y     Build path  Build Path Problem

Comment: Please find my below answer. 
[http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13448817/spring-apache-and-xml-error/16624128#16624128][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13448817/spring-apache-and-xml-error/16624128#16624128

Answer (score 1):

As to whatever you have mentioned, I am able to guess that the version of jre and apache tomcat that you were previously using somewhere differs from the one that you are trying to import into.

I suggest you to create a new project and navigate to the workspace (Don't use IDE to navigate, manually do so) then copy the folders src, Web-Content, ..... and replace it with the new ones.

Hope it helps.

Even after if it persists, right-click project root folder in eclipse, check if jre and apache are properly set and are not unbound.

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2239959/faceted-project-prblem-java-version-mismatch-error-message for detailed description on how to make the versions match

Answer (score 1):

So, I had this same issue and I just fixed it!

Actually what you would have done is Created or modified your project in IRAD or eclipse and with tomcat or websphere and its searching for the old server when you imported it to a new IDE.

In Order to solve this, You need to go to project facades and Click on Runtime and uncheck the wps v6.0 and click new below and select the Server which you have configured(In my case, it's to Tomcat 7) and BOOM!... It worked Fine B)[Check the image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mlTn9.png)

Answer (score 0):

Right Click project root folder -> Properties -> Targeted Runtime
Here Add/Select correct server.