# Error in my java web application after convert it to a maven project

Tags: eclipse, maven, m2e

I'm following a tutorial wich explains how to create a dynamic web project and convert it to a maven one. I have the m2e plugin installed in Eclipse, but after I right-click my project and convert it to maven, a red error icon is appearing in my project's root but when I open the folders inside it, there is no files with an error. I still tried to run the app but an 404 error message was the output. This is what Eclipse looks like:

[image]

Comment: Right-click the project, go `Maven -> Update Project`. Also, take a look in the `Problems View` (this one: http://mcuoneclipse.files.wordpress.com/2013/06/problems-view-with-messages-for-the-active-project.png ) what is the description of the problem there?

Comment: This issue can be solved with the solution provided on this thread
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2239959/faceted-project-prblem-java-version-mismatch-error-message