# IBM RAD - Java Compiler & Project Facets Mismatch

Tags: java, eclipse, facet, ibm-rad

I have installed both Java 1.6 & 1.7 on my system. I am using **IBM RAD 8.5** (Built on top of Eclipse) for development and Currently trying to see what errors/warnings I get in case I compiler by Java 1.6 build project with Java 1.7 compiler.

If I go to "Project->Properties->Java Compiler" then I am able to see version "1.7" among the listed Compiler Compliance Levels.
BUT when I go to the "Project->Properties->Project Facets" then I am able to see only facets upto 1.6 and 1.7 is NOT listed there.

When I try to compile this project by keeping project facets as 1.6 and compiler as 1.7 then I get Project Facets Mismatch error. The error says: -
Java Compiler Level does not match the version of the isntalled Java Project Facet.

Please suggest what changes do I need to do so that "1.7" becomes visible under the installed Java Project Facets. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

EDIT:

Did not read your Question carefully enough......

May try going to org.eclipse.wst.common.project.facet.core.xml which is located in your .settings folder of your Project and edit it manually to 1.7 like this:

```
<installed facet="java" version="1.7"/>
```

---

---

Looks like you have a faceted Project, maybe try going to Project->Properties->Project Facets and look if Java is set to 1.7.

[image]

Else if you are using maven put this

```
<properties>
         <maven.compiler.target>1.7</maven.compiler.target>
        <maven.compiler.source>1.7</maven.compiler.source>  

</properties>
```

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at below links. I hope it will help you to solve problem :-

[“Faceted Project Prblem (Java Version Mismatch)” error message - Stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2239959/faceted-project-prblem-java-version-mismatch-error-message)

[Eclipse: Java compiler level and project facet mismatch](http://codewriterstips.blogspot.in/2009/03/eclipse-java-compiler-level-and-project.html)

Answer (score 0):

You should change in (org.eclipse.wst.common.project.facet.core.xml) file.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<faceted-project>
  <installed facet="jst.ear" version="5.0"/>//version based on in your RAD
</faceted-project>
```